# Bypass Intranet traffic for proxy in chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, proxy, chromebook

I am working on an extension where proxy is set through my extension using chrome extension proxy api(`chrome.proxy.settings`). 
Everything works fine and I get all traffic on my proxy server. However, I am having trouble with the **intranet traffic**.

If I try to access any ip on my local network, my printer or any other system, I cannot. Is there a way to bypass the intranet requests so that they do not go through proxy? I found `<local>` but is not what I need.

Anyone faced a similar problem? Any direct method to bypass the same or any work around would be appreciated.

Comment: You could make the notion of "intranet" configurable, e.g. let the user input something like `192.168.0.0/16` that goes to the bypass list.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to bypass the intranet requests so that they do not go through proxy?

As far as I understand, *not automatically*. The notion of "intranet" is something not easily guessed - it depends on how your network is organized.

Perhaps you could allow the user to input network blocks that they consider intranet - in [CIDR notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing) that Chrome API accepts. The list of [private addresses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network) seems like a good default.

```js
var intranet_list = [
  "fd00::/8",
  "10.0.0.0/8",
  "172.16.0.0/12",
  "192.168.0.0/16",
  "<local>"
]; // Make this configurable

var config = {
  /* ... */
  rules: {
    /* ... */
    bypassList: intranet_list
  }
};
chrome.proxy.settings.set({
  value: config,
  scope: "regular"
});
```

Comment: Appreciate such a quick and detailed response @Xan. This can be a good solution with the defaults. However, the extension intents to monitor the web browsing traffic and allowing the user to make bypass list configurable is something I need to think on. 
Have been browsing a lot but do not seem to find  any direct bypass technique which could be put in bypass list without having to make it user configurable.

Comment: If we're talking about enterprise deployment, you could use `chrome.storage.managed` for administrator-defined config.

Comment: yes that helps for enterprise deployment. I am trying to concern with retail users too. The private addresses list is a good default too. Appreciate the help @Xan.

Comment: what if ip is 192.168.1.* ??   192.168.1.0/20? @xan